# Nuxt.js and forwarding cookie to backend

Tags: cookies, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I have site on nuxt.js (example.com) and backend on PHP (example.com/api/).

Some page get data from /api/some:

```
    asyncData() {
        return axios.get("http://example.com/api/some").then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        });
    },
```

In PHP-handler of "/api/some" I write to the log recieved cookies.
If I go to some-page by link (browser ajax-request) cookies exist.
If I refresh page (server-side rendering) then cookies is empty.

Cookie reach to nuxt (context.req.headers.cookie is not empty) but don't transfer to backend.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it work for axios.

```
const headers = {};
if (context.req) {
    headers.Cookie = context.req.headers.coookie;
}
return axios({
    url: url,
    method: "get",
    headers: headers,
}).then(/* ... */);
```